# Count the number of True booleans grouped together between False booleans and return in list

Tags: python

I have a list of booleans:

```
[False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

I am looking for a way to count the number of True values grouped together, separated by False values. For the above example, I would be looking for an output of `[3, 5, 7]`.

I have tried using groupby, and various counting methods but all I have been able to get so far is the total number of True values or the number of groups of True there are. My actual data will be a much longer list of booleans, is there a way to efficiently get this type of output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

bools = [False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]

print([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(bools) if key])
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, 
False, True, True, True, True, True, True,
        True, False]
groupList = []
flag = False
for i in list:
    if i:
        if flag is False:
            groupList.append(1)
            flag = True
        else:
            groupList[-1]+=1
    else:
        flag=False

print(groupList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`; you just need to process the result.

```
>>> x = [False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
>>> [sum(1 for _ in sg) for v, sg in groupby(x) if v]
[3, 5, 7]
```

---

The sequence produced by `groupby` consists of tuples of the key value and the subgroup corresponding to the key value. In this case, each list value *is* the key, so you get tuples like `(False, _grouper(...))`. `_grouper` is an implementation detail of `groupby`; all you need to worry about is that it is an iterable of like values in the original list.

Once you have the `groupby` instance, you can unpack each tuple, test if the first element is `True`, then compute the length of the corresponding `_grouper`. You can't use `len`, because an iterable isn't necessarily finite or pre-computed, so you use `sum` to add up a sequence of 1s for each element in the iterable. (Alternatively, you could use `len(list(sg))`.)

Answer (score -1):

is this what you mean

```
booleans=[False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, 
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
counter=0
for i in range(1, len(booleans)-1):
    if(booleans[i-1]==booleans[i+1] and booleans[i+1]==False):
        counter=counter+1
print(counter)
```